# Jade how do I prepend to a template in order to nest what is being prepended to?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

For example, I have:

```
block content
  h1 title
  div#someDiv
```

but I want to sometimes have it look like

```
block content
  h1 title
  div#wrapper
    div#someDiv
```

what is the best approach to get that wrapper there? I've thought about doing

```
block content
  h1 title
  if condition
    div#wrapper
      include stuff
  else
    include stuff
```

and then putting stuff in to a separate jade file. But that's really ugly.

I don't mind having 2 separate files for the 2 different cases, as long as I can keep things DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could pull out the header and have two separate block names.  I'm not sure why you have the `block content`, maybe you mean `block append content`?

```
h1 title
- if(condition) {
include with_wrapper
- } else {
include without_wrapper
- }
```

Comment: yeah, I suppose that would do. But this forces me into 3 separate files now.

Comment: You don't have to separate the layout into three separate files - you could squeeze it into two. But this leads to code duplication and makes your layout less extendable :(

Comment: lame. Ah well. I guess I'll do that